# Converging series - proof by negativity, not example

Tags: sequences-and-series

if:
$A_n+B_n$ and $A_n*B_n$ are converging series:
then atleast one of $A_n$ or $B_n$ are converging series.

I can prove it easily with negative example, but I want to prove it by using contradiction ( not example, but contradiction ).
my prove with example:
$A_n = 0,1,0,1$
$B_n = 1,0,1,0$
$lim(A_n+B_n) = 1$ (OFC with Limit to infinite )
$lim(B_n*A_n) = 0$ ( OFC with limit to infinite )
these both are converging series, but apart, they are not because they have 2 boundries,0 and 1.

my question:
How to prove it by Contradiction? I want to say this:
Suppose by negativity that An, Bn are indeed converging series, so if they are, then:
$LimA_n=L_a, LimB_n=L_b$ and here I am stuck.
Any tips will be welcomed, thanks in regards.

Edit:
I realized my mistake here, asked my teacher and he helped me with it.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wait, there was a comment here and I edited it? or I wrote and it got deleted? ( the other one comment, if i accidently edited it somehow, sorry )

Comment: Relax - I deleted my own comment. (I'd given a counterexample before seeing that you'd already given a different counterexample. I have no idea what you want here - the statement is false, and the right way to prove that is with an example! There cannot be a proof by contradiction that starts "Assume $A_n$ and $B_n$ are convergent, because that does not lead to a contradition - they **can** be convergent!)

Comment: I see, I guess its inevitable. I see there is no counterexample. Thanks for the help.